# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 11): TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancelToken' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

how to solve this error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 11):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancelToken' of undefined

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 11):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancelToken' of undefined

Comment: Use try catch to handle errors, if it's promise, await it in try catch, or use then() and catch() promise methods. Also, error says that object you try to use was undefined - guard that in if statement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*More information would be needed to debug the issue, but the following reference should help point you in the right direction.*

You need to make sure you handle every possible response when returning a promise response. You could use a [try catch block](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp) or [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) [.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods